# How to Delete data From eav database?

Tags: magento-1.7, database, sql, eav

i am trying to delete record from database is there any opposite methode of setdata to delete record from DB

```
$postModel = Mage::getModel('brainvire_brand/post');
$image=$data['image'];
$bname=$data['bname'];
$content=$data['content'];
$is_active=$data['is_active'];

$postModel->setBname($bname);
if($data['imagedelete'])
{
      $postModel->setImage('');
}
else
{
      $postModel->setImage($image);
}
$postModel->setContent($content);
$postModel->setIs_active($is_active);
```

Comment: Plz do not suggest me to add blank data

Comment: vaibhav,is flat table i.e single table model? ... not a eav tbale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,i Guss you have using  flat stucture

Better way to delete there any model by function `delete();`
By this you can delete model one by one.

```
$postModel = Mage::getModel('brainvire_brand/post');
$postModel->load($PkTablevalue);

$postModel->delete();
```

Example. For delete an product you can use:

```
$productObject = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$productObject->load($PID);
$productObject->delete();
```

According you comment you can unset a field value by `unsetData('index')`

just: `$postModel->unsetData('image');`
then `$postModel->save();`

Comment: i just want to delete one attribute value 

like i just want to delete value of image

Answer (score 2):

There is `unsetData()` which unsets the attribute in your PHP model but this results in the attribute just being ignored during save. To delete the attribute value, you need to set it to a value that is considered empty. What this can be depends on the backend type, but "null" always works.

Take a look at `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract::isValueEmpty()`:

```
public function isValueEmpty($value)
{
    $attrType = $this->getBackend()->getType();
    $isEmpty = is_array($value)
        || ($value === null)
        || $value === false && $attrType != 'int'
        || $value === '' && ($attrType == 'int' || $attrType == 'decimal' || $attrType == 'datetime');

    return $isEmpty;
}
```

I assume, "image" has the type 'varchar', so `setImage('')` will just set the value to an empty string, but `setImage(null)`  will actually remove it.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any opposite method of setData to delete record from DB.

No, I don't believe you can delete EAV table records using any Magento or magic methods. However, doing `setImage(null)` will effectively achieve what you want (removing `image` data, but not the actual DB record).